# C++ - Creating a temporary object with decltype or auto

Tags: c++

I have an object "a" and I want to copy it into an object "b" but modify it a bit without modifying "a". Then that would look like this:

```
class SomeClass{

public:
    int a;

public:
    SomeClass(int _a)       {a = _a;}
    SomeClass& doStuff()    {++a; return *this;}

};

const SomeClass a( 25);
const auto b = SomeClass( a).doStuff();
```

This works nice but lets say I don't now / don't want to write the type of "a", then I came up with this solution:

```
const auto b = std::remove_const<decltype( a)>::type( a).doStuff();
```

Am I doing this right? Is there a less ugly solution for this? (where I don't have to type "a" twice.) Using auto or something. Preferably not a macro.

Comment: If it is a temporary object, why does it have to be const? Otherwise, you could simply do `SomeClass b(a); b.doStuff();`...

Comment: Is this operation required only once? If it is not then maybe it would be better do add special constructor?

Comment: @Aconcagua "b" needs to be const. When I wrote "temporary" I meant the object that is constructed from "a" and then assigned to "b", my bad

Comment: @VTT It had a special constructor originally that took "const SomeClass&" as parameter and a "flag" enum but I was looking for a nicer solution

Comment: @AdyAdy I personally would consider VTT's/your original approach the nicest -- *if* you give the enum parameter a *default* value...

Comment: A better approach would be to make a distinguished wrapper type for `SomeClass` reference dedicated to  `doStuff` operation and make constructor accepting this type. This approach eliminates possible overhead of creating a temporary `SomeClass` object and of passing an extra parameter into constructor.

Comment: @Aconcagua I always used that but then I ended up with lots of constructors for example my Vec3 class had a ton of constructors. Also if I use "enum class" then I need to write the scope, that kinda defeats the purpose of auto / decltype.

Comment: @VTT I kinda forgot about the performance overhead because I used this with very simple classes. Like: Vec3 b = Vec3( a).invert(), and I looked at the generated assembly and it was the same as with Vec3 b = Vec3( a, INVERT_FLAG). With more complicated classes it makes sense, can you give a very simple example of what you mean be the wrapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
template<typename T>
T copy(const T& t) { return T(t); }

const auto b = copy(a).doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating VTT's comment:

```
class SomeClass;
class DoStuff
{
    friend class SomeClass;
    SomeClass const& c;
public:
    explicit DoStuff(SomeClass const& c)
        : c(c)
    { }
};

class SomeClass
{
    int a;
public:
    SomeClass(int a)
        : a(a)
    { }

    SomeClass(SomeClass const& other)
        : a(other.a)
    { }

    SomeClass(DoStuff d)
        : SomeClass(d.c)
    {
        doStuff();
    }
};

SomeClass const a(7);
SomeClass const b((DoStuff(a)));
```

Only unlucky drawback: we need additional parentheses to prevent from b being interpreted as function `SomeClass const b (DoStuff a) { }` with `a` as parameter name...

I personally would have preferred making DoStuff an inner class of SomeClass, but that would have forced you to repeat the class name again:

```
SomeClass const b (( SomeClass::DoStuff(d) ));
```

(Haha, now I got myself - *one* repetition of the class name I still have even without the inner class...)

OK, before anyone moans:

```
SomeClass const b { DoStuff(a) };
```

Lately mentioned? Well, guess, I personally absolutely do *not* appreciate this syntax and avoid it wherever possible - even with initialiser lists, I still place parentheses around: `std::vector<int> v({7, 10, 12});` – but that's a different topic...

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to make a distinguished wrapper type for `SomeClass` reference dedicated to `doStuff` operation and make constructor accepting this type. This approach eliminates possible overhead of creating a temporary `SomeClass` object and of passing an extra parameter into constructor. Though it does not make much difference if `SomeClass` is a rather simple.

```
class
t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap final
{
    #pragma region Fields

    private: SomeClass const & m_inst;

    #pragma endregion

    private:
    t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap(void) = delete;

    public:
    t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap(t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap const & that) noexcept
    :   m_inst{that.m_inst}
    {}      

    public: explicit
    t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap(SomeClass const & inst) noexcept
    :   m_inst{inst}
    {}

    private: t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap &
    operator =(t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap const & that) = delete;

    private: t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap &
    operator =(t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap && that) = delete;

    public: SomeClass const &
    Unwrap(void) const noexcept
    {
        return(m_inst);
    }
};

// inside of SomeClass definition:
public: explicit
SomeClass(t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap const wrap)
:   a{wrap.Unwrap().a}
{
    doStuff();
}

//  actual use
const SomeClass b{t_DoingStuffSomeClassWrap{a}};
```

Comment: I see, you decided to elaborate your proposition yourself now... But we both oversaw one small issue: `/* actual use:*/ SomeClass b(/*...*/);` - well, we need to repeat the class name again - this is what only molbdnilo avoids...

Comment: Oh, by the way: these pragmas are non-standard, but MSVC specific - prefer not to use them on SO unless the question is MSVC specific, too... Why don't you simply have one public and one private section?

Comment: (1) I'm working on making these pragmas less MSVC specific. (2) It's actually simpler to use per item access specifier as it allows you to group items depending on their purpose instead of depending on access, simplifies refactoring - you only need to change access specifier instead moving entire method into different location, improves readability because there is no need to scroll up to figure out what kind of access does current item have.

Comment: On (2), I cannot agree with you: While you, who is developping the class, might find that reasonable, for me, the developer *using* your class, the issue is totally inverted: I am nearly exclusively interested in the public interface, as the private one, I cannot use anyway. However, the public interface is distributed all over the class, and it is easy to miss one of the public functions with all this public/private switching. So for me, the user, readability is lost instead...

Comment: @Aconcagua Your point is not really valid. It only makes sense for developer using this code to look directly into the source code when he wants to get some insights on implementation details. When he is only interested in public methods then he will take a look at class browser or just use autocompletion. Please notice that listing class members by access, by kind (static / non-static field / function) or alphabetically can be done easily while automatically listing related items based on purpose is not possible unless they are already written sorted like this.

Comment: While class browser and autocompletion sure are nice features, I think you clearly underestimate the number of people still reading headers even in those days... There are several coding guide lines out there mandating first public, then protected, then private section in the headers - not sure now if e. g. MISRA C++ is among these, too, but at least could imagine quite well.

Comment: Common practice at least differs from your style - actually, it is the first time in >15 years I see applying accesibility to every member in C++, although familiar with this from Java (but even there normally methods are sorted by visibility...). Don't get me wrong, I don't dare to criticise - just noticed a quite unusual practice...

Comment: @Aconcagua I admit that it does differ from common practice, but only from common practice in C++. If you look at other languages you'll notice that approach with per-item access specifier is used almost everywhere these days: C#, D, Rust, Java, Typescript etc. The reduced readability of access sections seems to be acknowledged by the standard committee (for example [Group Member Specifiers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3955.pdf) proposal to extend section syntax was rejected because it would reduce code readability).

Comment: The only reason for existence of access sections in C++ that I can think of is that such syntax reduces source code size (which probably was a valid reason at the time C++ was initially designed). Also even in Java a [best practices suggest to group methods by functionality](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627193836/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html).

Comment: You got the point: This is C++, not Java, C#, ... Here we clearly separate between declaration (header) and implementation (source) (*can*, at least, and *do* if we are consequent), a concept unkown to Java and C# (partial classes are not an equivalent...) at least. Templates seem to break this only at a first glance as we can add the implementation *after* the class (within header itself or a separate file included by the former). And we can easily apply different grouping for declaration (first visibility, then functionality) and implementation (functionality only -- rest don't care).

Comment: Not sure about the rejected proposition proofing the mentioned akcnowledgement: It is easy to separete only three different sections, but this true section forest evolving simply gets too complicated. One point I must admit, though: C++ requires *discipline* to get a clean interface (at most three sections: public, protected, private), C++ allwoing to switch arbitrarily between sections is a little unfortunate in this respect... But one has to be disciplined even more with your approach: not being forced to apply the visibility easily lets fall a function into the bad section on forgetting...

Comment: Might be my fault, perhaps I've been hanging around with C++ for too long, but for me, your code scheme is *much* more difficult to read than the classic approach...