# C++ - Calling copy assignment from move assignment operator

Tags: c++

Take a simple class where the move assignment does essentially the same as the copy assignment plus maybe changes some things in the source object.

In such case is it a good design to call the copy-assignment from the move-assignment?

```
SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& source) {if( this != &source){ /*copy stuff*/}                    return *this;}
SomeClass& operator=(SomeClass&&      source) {if( this != &source){ *this = source; /*modify source*/} return *this;}
```

Is it safe to assume that all current (and future) compilers will treat `source` as a normal reference in `*this = source`, even though originally `source` is passed as rvalue reference (`&&`)? So the move assignment won't call itself recursively. Or is it better to just make a protected `copy(source)` method and call that from both operators?

Comment: Such move assignment would be exceptionally confusing for the class users. Using a regular method with proper name would be much better. If you want to still use assignment operator to perform this action you should wrap `source` reference into distinguished type dedicated to perform this action. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583927/c-creating-a-temporary-object-with-decltype-or-auto/45585743#45585743).

Comment: @VTT Not sure I understand you. The class users don't know about the implementation so why is it confusing to them?

Comment: The users don't know about implementation, however they have certain expectations of what move assignment supposed to do. And nobody expects move assignment to copy stuff modifying it in the process. Including library functions. If you have a `vector<SomeClass>` and for example try to sort it library function most likely will prefer to utilize move assignment as more efficient and will end up messing entire vector with modified copies.

Comment: @VTT It modifies the source after the copy.

Comment: Even though moved object supposed to left in "valid but unspecified" state modifying source object after copy does not make sense as it is supposed to be reinitialized somehow before used again.

Comment: @VTT It calls the copy-assignment not the move-assignment.

Comment: It calls copy assignment internally, however since it happens inside of move assignment operator so moved object supposed to be reinitialized somehow before used again.

Comment: @VTT Sometimes, the move constructor *must* modify the source object. For example a smart pointer must clear the pointer in the source object otherwise you will get a double delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that all current (and future) compilers will treat `source` as a normal reference in `*this = source`, even though originally source is passed as rvalue reference (`&&`)?

It's not a matter of what guarantees a compiler will give you in future, it's a matter of how the language rules on that.
`source` within your move assignment operator is an lvalue the type of which is `SomeClass &&`. Therefore `*this = source` invokes the copy assignment operator for it expects an lvalue reference, that is what you are actually providing.
It would have been different if you did `*this = std::move(source)` within your move assignment operator instead ([see it here if you want](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ma1GIEm4S9vXFuCj), a *segfault* is probably the best you can get out of it).

That being said, if it's or not a *good design* is mainly opinion-based from my point of view, so I cannot reply. Anyway, as long as semantics of copy and move assignments are honored, I don't see any reason to blame a class because of how it implements the two operators.

Comment: What would happen when they do `*this = std::move(source)`?

Comment: @juanchopanza If you did it within the move assignment operator we can sum up with [shooting in your feet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ma1GIEm4S9vXFuCj).