# How to create a temporary when a const lvalue reference is used to initialize an rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++14

Following code:

```
struct T {};
const T& foo();
void bar(T&& arg);

bar(T(foo()));
```

The last line is correct, but it uses T directly. If T is somewhat more complex (e.g. involving templates), then the line gets ugly.
Since we have `std::move` and `std::forward`, I wonder if there is something similar in the standard lib for the above case. Something like

```
template<class T>
T make_temporary(const T& arg) { return arg; }
```

Provides the standard an appropriate solution?

Comment: I do not see anything [in utility](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/utility) like that.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that `auto(foo())` does not work. Hence, [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45583927/3233393).

Comment: Per Quentin, does this answer your question? [C++ - Creating a temporary object with decltype or auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583927/c-creating-a-temporary-object-with-decltype-or-auto)

Comment: The other discussion doesn't answer my question. Actually I guessed, that the standard provides a simple solution for this simple problem, which I have just overlooked. Something like the solution suggested by Quentin. Alas, my guess was wrong.